# Export grease pencil lines with a transparent background

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

How can I export (as PNG frames) the lines of grease pencil on a transparent background?

Comment: Also remember to set up the PNG output as RGBA!

Answer (score 2):

There's an entry in the *Properties Window > Render* panel named *Film*. Open it and set a hook at *Transparent*.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the [*Render properties*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/render.html) Panel and scroll down to *Film* and check the *Transparent* checkbox.
[image: Grease Pencil selecting transparent background in output properties]

Rendering your piece should now produce a transparent background, rendering only yours lines:

[image: Rendering grease pencil lines with a transparent background]

For additional reference, here's Grant Abbitt with quick and easy 2 minute video on [Blender rendering with transparent backgrounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zukb9mlFtbk&feature=emb_title).